# Program to check whether two strings are anagrams of each other

Tags: java, beginner, strings

I have written this code and I am wondering if the code could be optimised.Please review.

```
 public class Anagram1{
   public static boolean check(char[] c1,char[] c2,int l1,int l2){

     /*if the lengths of the strings are not equal,they cannot be anagrams of each other */

    if(l1!=l2){
        return false;
    }

    int count = 0;

    //nested for loops to compare the characters of both strings.
    //if the characters match,then the strings are anagrams of each other.
    for(int i=0; i<l1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<l2; j++){
            if(c1[i]==c2[j]){
                count++;
                break;      //"break" used so as to count only a single occurrence of a
            }               //character.
        }
    }
    if(count==l1 && count==l2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "abcd";

    String s2 = "acdb";

    char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();

    char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();

    int l1 = s1.length();

    int l2 = s2.length();

    System.out.println(check(c1,c2,l1,l2));
  }
}
```

Comment: Most answers seem to only look for anagrams in words. In your scenario, are you looking to check if phrases are anagrams of each other? Consider the following: "Anagram" and "Nag a ram" (Thanks Google)

Comment: don't use old-school for-int loops. use the fast enumeration Java has. It looks better, removes a useless variable, and in some cases takes care of things like concurrency checks.

Comment: @akadian - I don't think that I have to check for that condition unless otherwise specified because, in the language of computer,both the strings are conspicuously different.

Comment: @MayankGupta I know that they are different in strings, my comment was mainly referring to the definition of an anagram. It doesn't add much, but just figured you might want to specify on your definition. Anagram: "...the result of rearranging the letters of a word or phrase to produce a new word or phrase..." It's your program, so it's really up to you, but otherwise you just need to ignore white space from your input strings to compare.

Answer (score 5):

About the algorithm (ITS NOT CORRECT). I will still review it for you:

- Passing `l1` and `l2` in `boolean check(char[] c1,char[] c2,int l1,int l2)` as argument is redundant. You can use the inherent `c1.length` and `c2.length` provided by Java.
- `if(count==l1 && count==l2)` Any one check would do as you overruled `l1!=l2` very early. Remember?
- Failure cases:
  "aab" and "abb" both would be called anagrams. Hope you discover that.

About the algorithm:

- There are simpler better ways to check if two strings are anagram. How? Sort the strings and compare character by character.
  Not impressed? Do a character count using a Map for each character and compare it for other array. And there are many more. Happy Googling.

Comment: I believe he used the word anagram instead of palindrome.

Comment: My bad :) Updated the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution doesn't exactly work. For example, if you use:

```
String s1 = "abbd";
String s2 = "acdb";
```

You will find that it returns true even though each character in s2 does not appear in s1.

See my solution below which will work for any two strings to ensure they are anagrams.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Anagram1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "abcd";
        String s2 = "adbc";
        System.out.println(check(s1, s2));
    }

    public static boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
        // Remove white space and change to lower case.
        s1 = s1.replace(" ","").toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.replace(" ","").toLowerCase();

        // If they are equal, return true. If they are not the same length,
        // return false.
        if (s1.equals(s2)) {
            return true;
        } else if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }

        // Convert to ArrayList for sorting.
        ArrayList<Character> sl1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ArrayList<Character> sl2 = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (char ch1 : s1.toCharArray()) {
            sl1.add(ch1);
        }

        for (char ch2 : s2.toCharArray()) {
            sl2.add(ch2);
        }

        // Sort both ArrayLists
        Collections.sort(sl1);
        Collections.sort(sl2);

        // If they are equal return true, else return false.
        if (sl1.equals(sl2)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, I use two `ArrayList`s (one for each `String`) to sort them into alphabetical order and then compare the results to see if they are equal.
This solution takes into account repeating characters and it ensures that both `String`'s include all the characters (not just checking one against the other).

EDIT: Thanks to @Akadian for pointing out the case where a phrase is passed in, to address this you can use the replace method for the String class to remove any whitespaces, also in case the phrase is capitalised you would need to call toLowerCase() to ignore the case of specific letters.

Comment: Hi Adam, I think we should avoid providing solutions here. Instead hint at the issue and solution. Let the thirsty find the water with little pebbles you provide :)

Comment: If OP includes phrases in his definiton of anagrams, you should remove white-spaces at the beginning of the check function. This will make you exit early when comparing the length despite having a potential anagram.

Comment: @thepace fair enough :)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a few different problems with your code. One small problem is you break if the `length`s are not the same, but

```
if(count==l1 && count==l2){
        return true;
}
```

still checks if they both equal. One of those can be removed as it will always be true.

Another problem I have found is that if you put the `break` in the loops to check for more than one occurrence of a character, but if you hand trace it, it is not actually doing this.

Let's go over the loops.

You are taking one character from `c1` and checking it against all characters from `c2`. If they match, you add one to count and break out of the `c2` loop and get the next char of `c1`. Then you start over.

It sounds like a good plan, except that you start at the beginning of `c2` again. So if `c1` has multiple characters, it only recognizes the first character in `c2` as matching. This will give you problems later on. Changing your input to `"aabcd" "acgdb"` will fool your logic.

I did it a different way, utilizing a `HashMap`and a ternary operator. Using a `HashMap` like this will help you in the long run, as it maps a `char` to an `int`, in this case one character and the amount of them. Doing this for each input will give you two maps, either identical or not.

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    //Diff lengths = false
    System.out.println(check("acd", "bacd"));
    //Same letters, mixed = true
    System.out.println(check("abcd", "bacd"));
    //Same string = true
    System.out.println(check("abcd", "abcd"));
    //Diff letters = false
    System.out.println(check("abcd", "gacd"));
    //Same characters = true
    System.out.println(check("abcd123$", "1b2a3c$d"));
    //Multiple occurances of a letter = true
    System.out.println(check("aaacddbg", "acadadgb"));
}

public static boolean check(String c1, String c2){
    if(c1.length() != c2.length()){
        return false;
    }

    char[] word1 = c1.toCharArray();
    char[] word2 = c2.toCharArray();

    Map<Character, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < word1.length; i++){
        map1.put(word1[i], (map1.get(word1[i]) == null) ? 1 : map1.get(word1[i])+1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++){
        map2.put(word2[i], (map2.get(word2[i]) == null) ? 1 : map2.get(word2[i])+1);
    }

    if(map1.equals(map2)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider extracting `map1.get(word1[i])` and `map2.get(word2[i])` in those `for` loops into variables for a (presumably) small performance improvement (in a situation where a string contains duplicated characters you call `map#.get(word#[i])` twice for each of those characters).